# Override properties in bootstrap.yml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I want to override property defined in `bootstrap.yml` right after it is loaded.

eg: need to override/define `spring.cloud.vault.secret-id` based on some condition. How I can achieve same before spring-cloud-vault use secret-id property to connect to vault server.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You can add an application listener and once the application context is loaded you can check your condition and replace the value in Environment class

Comment: by that time, spring-cloud-config already hit vault server to fetch secrets. So this approach is not working. I tried implementing "ApplicationListener"  that is getting triggered before hitting vault server but implementation is not using properties set in my code and picking one defined in bootstrap.yml.